# Slimming an xml

Tags: python, xml, xslt, compression

I've a program producing one big xml every day and I want to save space, and there are some information that are not usefull after some time. I want to remove this information, for example my xml is now:

```
<owner name="thename">
   <datasets ndatasets="10" size="10000">
       <dataset size="100" creationdate="...">mydataset1</dataset>
       <dataset size="200" creationdate="...">mydataset2</dataset>
       ...
   </datasets>
</owner>
<owner name="thename2">
  ...
</owner>
```

I want to remove the information on the single datasets, so I want to tranform it in:

```
<owner name="thename">
   <datasets ndatasets="10" size="10000" />
</owner>
<owner name="thename2">
  ...
</owner>
```

What is the easiest way to do it? I'm using python, but also other easy and portable solutions are welcome

Comment: XSLT is an easy way to do it: just copy the <datasets></datasets> but not the child elements - and leave the rest of the XML the same.

Comment: I've never use it: can you provide a snippet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**An XSLT solution** (Sean's solution is good, but it would stop working if elements or nodes other that `dataset` were made children of `datasets`):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="datasets/node()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided skeletal XML** (wrapped into a single top element to make it a well-formed XML document):

```
<t>
    <owner name="thename">
        <datasets ndatasets="10" size="10000">
            <dataset size="100" creationdate="...">mydataset1</dataset>
            <dataset size="200" creationdate="...">mydataset2</dataset>
        </datasets>
    </owner>
    <owner name="thename2">
        <datasets ndatasets="10" size="10000">
            <dataset size="100" creationdate="...">mydataset1</dataset>
            <dataset size="200" creationdate="...">mydataset2</dataset>
        </datasets>
    </owner>
</t>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<t>
   <owner name="thename">
      <datasets ndatasets="10" size="10000"/>
   </owner>
   <owner name="thename2">
      <datasets ndatasets="10" size="10000"/>
   </owner>
</t>
```

**Explanation**:

Proper use of the identity rule and overriding it with an empty-body template matching any child-node of `datasets`.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an XSLT 1.0 style-sheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
 <xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="dataset" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is a couple of pointers to get you started on your XSLT journey:

- http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442827/good-books-on-xslt

Comment: One way to actually use the XSLT is through the python lxml module: http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#xslt

Answer (score 2):

I think @Sean B. Durkin answer is simpler but if you want to do it the hard way with `lxml`:

```
from lxml import etree
from StringIO import StringIO

xml = etree.parse(StringIO('''<owner name="thename">
      <datasets ndatasets="10" size="10000">
        <dataset size="100" creationdate="...">mydataset1</dataset>
        <dataset size="200" creationdate="...">mydataset2</dataset>
      </datasets>
      </owner>'''))

[d.getparent().remove(d) for d in  xml.findall('.//dataset')]
print etree.tostring(xml, pretty_print=True)
```

The result:

```
<owner name="thename">
<datasets ndatasets="10" size="10000">
   </datasets>
</owner>
```